# Posting Data To Mysql with IDs

Tags: php, mysql, count, str-replace

I have a form with some input texts. It's counted with the name + an id. Like:

megnevezes_1
megnevezes_2

My form has also a counted id tag, called tid_1 and go on.

When I post my form i made a hidden input called darab, which counts how many id's I have.

Then I do the mysql query:

```
for($k=1; $k=$darab; $k++){
$command = <<<HTML
UPDATE
    $dbtablename_template_tetelek
    SET
    vamtarifa_szj = '$vamtarifa_szj_$k',
    megnevezes = '$megnevezes_$k',
    me_egyseg = '$me_egyseg_$k',
    mennyiseg = '$mennyiseg_$k',
    afa = '$afa_$k',
    egyseg_ar = 'str_replace(".","",$egyseg_ar_$k)'
    WHERE template_id = '$tid_$k'

HTML;

mysql_query($command,$kapcsolat) or die(mysql_error(). $command);
}
```

But theres something wrong with it. How to attach to my strings the $k string with _? And how to make the str replace in the query?

Comment: better do all the PHP processing above the query. like.. `$blah = $egyseg_ar . '_' . $k;`

Comment: what is that `str_replace` trying to do? Are you trying to literally insert some php code into a db field? or do you expect the text to be replaced before being assigned to egyseg_ar in the db? either way... won't work. php functions don't execute in heredocs, mysql knows nothing about php code, and you're forming a syntax error ($egseg_ar_$k will be a bare string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
for($k=1; $k=$darab; $k++){

$blah = $egyseg_ar . '_' . $k;
$replace = str_replace(".", "", $blah);

$command = <<<HTML
UPDATE
    $dbtablename_template_tetelek
    SET
    vamtarifa_szj = '$vamtarifa_szj_$k',
    megnevezes = '$megnevezes_$k',
    me_egyseg = '$me_egyseg_$k',
    mennyiseg = '$mennyiseg_$k',
    afa = '$afa_$k',
    egyseg_ar = $replace
    WHERE template_id = '$tid_$k'

HTML;

mysql_query($command,$kapcsolat) or die(mysql_error(). $command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let PHP know precisely what it needs to parse. To help it you can use curly brackets like in `'{$var1}_{$var2}'`

So e.g. `mennyiseg = '$mennyiseg_$k'` might need to be `mennyiseg = '{$mennyiseg}_{$k}'` if you already have a variable named `$mennyiseg` in your code above the loop.